# Nodejs rest api mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to display all members from MYSQL database with Node Js. But I get some errors. My database name is apibase and I have table members (id, name, email, phone) My code is below:

```
 //routes.js file
    const pool = require('../data/config');


    const router = app => {

        app.get('/', (request, response) => {
            response.send({
                message: 'Welcome to the Node.js Express REST API!'
            });
        });

        // Display all users
        app.get('/members', (request, response) => {
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM members', (error, result) => {
                if (error) throw error;

                response.send(result);
            });
        });

        // Display a single user by ID
        app.get('/members/:id', (request, response) => {
            const id = request.params.id;

            pool.query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?', id, (error, result) => {
                if (error) throw error;

                response.send(result);
            });
        });

    }

    module.exports = router;
```

And my database.js file:

```
 const mysql = require('mysql');
 const config = {
 host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
 database: 'apibase',
 };

const pool = mysql.createPool(config);

 module.exports = pool;
```

And app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/routes')
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
}));

routes(app);


const server = app.listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) return console.log(`Error: ${error}`);

    console.log(`Server listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

I don't know what is the problem with this code, can somebody help me with this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ShubhDixit I'm using https://c9.io/ for development, and error is "ECONNRESET: Request could not be proxied!"

Comment: you should change the host in your configuration of mysql ,are you sure its localhost and root ??

Comment: @ShubhDixit Ohh my mistake, thank you.